# Play Framework 2.5 JavaAsync throwing CompletionException

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using Play 2.5 to build a simple app. For better performance I'm using Akka chunked response with Java 8 CompletionStage strategy. Below is the code by which chunked response is getting generated(it's working fine when not using ComperableFuture):

```
@Singleton
public class AbstractSource {

    public Source<ByteString, ?> getChunked(String html) {

        return Source.<ByteString>actorRef(256, OverflowStrategy.dropNew())
                .mapMaterializedValue(sourceActor -> {
                    sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString(html), null);
                    sourceActor.tell(new Status.Success(NotUsed.getInstance()), null);
                    return null;
                });

    }

}
```

And here is my controller:

```
@Singleton
@AddCSRFToken
public class Application extends Controller {

    @Inject
    private AbstractSource abstractSource;

    public CompletionStage<Result> index() {


        CompletionStage<Source<ByteString, ?>> source = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                                                  abstractSource.getChunked(index.render(CSRF.getToken(request()).map(t -> 
                                                    t.value()).orElse("no token")).body()
                                                   )
                                                );

        return source.thenApply( chunks -> ok().chunked(chunks));

    }

}
```

Now when I'm running the app it's throwing following exception:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:269)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:195)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:98)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:57)
    at play.mvc.Controller.request(Controller.java:36)
    at com.mabsisa.ui.web.controllers.Application.lambda$index$1(Application.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

I'm not using HTTP context anywhere, so why this is not working I'm not getting. Same code is working when returning normal Result with chunked response. Please help with this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *have to* supply the HTTP execution context when dealing with `CompletableFuture` / `CompletionStage`. In Scala the context information is passed via implicits, these are not available in Java - this is why Play uses `ThreadLocal`.

However you can lose this information when switching threads and that is why you have the problem. You *may* think that you don't access the HTTP context but actually you do - you are using `request()`.

So you have to change your code to use `supplyAsync` with an Executor:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-

From this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> abstractSource.getChunked(index.render(CSRF.getToken(request()).map(t -> 
                                                    t.value()).orElse("no token")).body()
                                                   )
                                                );
```

to this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> abstractSource.getChunked(index.render(CSRF.getToken(request()).map(t -> 
                                                    t.value()).orElse("no token")).body()
                                                   )
                                                , ec.current());
```

where `ec` is your context: `@Inject HttpExecutionContext ec;`

Comment: awsome answer with good explanation......one more thing want to ask if this is a good design approach in play or not? cn you please share your opinion?

Comment: Returning a `CompletionStage<Result>` is the _de facto_ standard to define async actions in Play 2.5, so you are fine here. Regarding chunked responses in Play: take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaStream#Chunked-responses - by using Akka streams you are already on a good track so don't worry here either - your design approach is good!

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: This is filed as https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6452 and there is documentation here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#Java-thread-locals

Comment: Good answer, but if i correctly understand you pass Default Play Executor to CompletableFuture this cause block request executor if you do heavy task in your async

Comment: @MojtabaAsg this is absolutely correct. Look at the answer as a guidance. If you intend to do heavy computation it might be good idea to provide another execution context which you tune according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to **Anton's** answer.

If you are building a non-blocking app using Play Java API, it might become quite cumbersome to inject `HttpExecutionContext` and pass `ec.current())` every time you need to call methods on `CompletionStage`.

To make life easier you can use a decorator, which will preserve the context between calls.

```
public class ContextPreservingCompletionStage<T> implements CompletionStage<T> {

    private HttpExecutionContext context;
    private CompletionStage<T> delegate;

    public ContextPreservingCompletionStage(CompletionStage<T> delegate,
                                            HttpExecutionContext context) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

So you will need to pass context only once:

```
return new ContextPreservingCompletionStage<>(someCompletableFuture, context)
                            .thenCompose(something -> {...});
                            .thenApply(something -> {...});
```

Instead of

```
return someCompletableFuture.thenComposeAsync(something -> {...}, context.current())
                            .thenApplyAsync(something -> {...}, context.current());
```

That is particularly useful if you are building a multi-tier app, and passing `CompletionStage`s between different classes.

Full decorator implementation example [is here](https://gist.github.com/yury-kislaik/f143adb78516b9c97f4808e4305953e3).