# Play 2.5 upgrade error: CompletionException - There is no HTTP Context available from here

Tags: java, scala, java-8, akka, playframework-2.5

After upgrading from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5 on a sample app, when I run `./activator clean dist`, I get no errors however after going to a specific endpoint `http://localhost:9000/java/proxy`, I'm receiving the following error:

```
[error] application - 

! @72keog237 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/java/proxy] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:604)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:62)
    at play.mvc.Controller.response(Controller.java:81)
    at controllers.JavaController$4.apply(JavaController.java:107)
    at controllers.JavaController$4.apply(JavaController.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
```

I have been using the guide from the [Replaced F.Promise with Java 8's CompletionStage](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/releases/release25/migration25/JavaMigration25.md) replacing F.Promise, map, and flatMap with the suggested replacements from the previous link (reflected snippet of changes below).

```
  public CompletionStage<Result> proxy() {
    final  CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url("http://example.com").get();

    Logger.info("Before map");
    final CompletionStage<Result> resultPromise = responsePromise.thenApplyAsync(
        new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
          @Override
          public Result apply(WSResponse wsResponse) {
            Logger.info("Within map");
            response().setContentType(wsResponse.getHeader("Content-Type"));
            return ok(wsResponse.getBody());
          }
        }
    );
```

When going back to 2.4, I don't get this error and the `http://localhost:9000/java/proxy` endpoint works successfully.

After replacing the appropriate replacement calls in the `proxy` method using this [public sample app on github](https://github.com/btgrant-76/Play-2-Java-Scala-Java-8-Async-Comparison/blob/6a85cf31cfb804ef20bacf8e14d30ce46cc9307c/app/controllers/JavaController.java#L86-L99), I keep getting the `no HTTP Context available` error above. I also get the same result with `http://localhost:9000/java8/proxy` endpoint in the [Java8Controller class](https://github.com/btgrant-76/Play-2-Java-Scala-Java-8-Async-Comparison/blob/6a85cf31cfb804ef20bacf8e14d30ce46cc9307c/app/controllers/Java8Controller.java#L71-L83).

I found others who have come across this problem and so far I've been able to conjecture that I need a [HttpExecutionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198375/how-to-use-http-context-current-in-a-promise-in-play/23204616#23204616) call and/or use [supplyAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236209/play-framework-2-5-javaasync-throwing-completionexception) although I've been having trouble transferring that knowledge to this example. Perhaps someone can give an example or two (or three) on how I may resolve this error? Any suggestions welcome, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync#Using-CompletionStage-inside-an-Action), you must supply the HTTP execution context explicitly as an executor when using a Java CompletionStage inside an Action.
 So you can inject HTTP Context in your Action.

```
public class Application extends Controller {
@Inject HttpExecutionContext ec;

public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
    someCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { 
      // do something with request()
    }, ec.current());
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.