# Scheduler - TaskInvocation - There is no HTTP Context available from here. Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have created a task to run every hour from my Play framework app using the guide found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks#Using-Guice-Dependency-Injection).

This works perfectly, the task it automates is storing notifications in the database at particular dates.

Now I am trying to send an email to accompany the notification. This works too, with hard coded text. However I need to use `Messages` for future translation.

To do this I created an email template in which I pass the message keys to the email template. Which would work normally as part of the app.

This causes the Scheduler to output the following error:

```
[error] a.d.TaskInvocation - There is no HTTP Context available from here.
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:68)
    at play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$.ctx(TemplateMagicForJava.scala:21)
    at play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$.implicitJavaMessages(TemplateMagicForJava.scala:36)
    at views.html.emailtemplates.reminder$.apply(reminder.template.scala:48)
    at views.html.emailtemplates.reminder$.render(reminder.template.scala:65)
    at views.html.emailtemplates.reminder.render(reminder.template.scala)
    at api.Scheduler.Scheduler.lambda$runHourlyScheduleChecks$0(Scheduler.java:44)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:101)
```

Which I believe is caused by the call to Messages in the email scala template:

```
@Messages(titleMessageKey)
```

How can I access Messages from the scheduled task?

My Scheduler Class:

> Please note hourly task is running every minute for development
>   purposes.

```
public class Scheduler {

    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private final ExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Inject
    public Scheduler(ActorSystem actorSystem, ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        this.actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // delay
                Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES), // interval
                runHourlyScheduleChecks(),
                this.executionContext
        );
    }

    private Runnable runHourlyScheduleChecks(){

        return () -> {
            Logger.info("api.Scheduler.Scheduler.runHourlyScheduleChecks() - Starting automated hourly schedule checker.");

            Notifications.sendDueNotifications();

            Logger.info("api.Scheduler.Scheduler.runHourlyScheduleChecks() - Schedule checker complete.");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608504/play-2-5-upgrade-error-completionexception-there-is-no-http-context-available

Comment: @Simon I have looked at that before however I don't think it applies as I am running a task and not using a standard controller method. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: We have the same problem. We were sending the emails using scheduler rendered from twirl until upgrade to Play. 2.6. Now we have "There is no HTTP Context available from here." because of ctx in TemplateMagicForJava.