# Play 2.6 There is no HTTP Context available from here. error upon action execution

Tags: asynchronous, httpcontext, playframework-2.6

all.
I'm new to the Play Framework and to asynchronous programming in general.  I've started a new project and am running into an issue in an action controller.  As far as I can tell, I'm properly injecting the Http Context in the controller structured like the play-java-ebean-example project on github  shown in this code:

```
private final ListBillGroupRepository groupRepository;
private final ListBillExtractDetailRepository extractRepository;
private final FormFactory formFactory;
private final HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext;

@Inject
public ListBillGroupController(FormFactory formFactory,
                               ListBillGroupRepository groupRepository,
                               ListBillExtractDetailRepository extractRepository,
                               HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext) {
    this.extractRepository = extractRepository;
    this.groupRepository = groupRepository;
    this.formFactory = formFactory;
    this.httpExecutionContext = httpExecutionContext;
}
```

I have the following action code in the same controller that seems to be the issue:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> editGroup(Long groupId, int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    CompletableFuture<PagedList<ListBillExtractDetail>> pageFuture =
            extractRepository.page(groupId, page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).toCompletableFuture();
    CompletableFuture<List<BigDecimal>> listFuture =
            extractRepository.totals(groupId).toCompletableFuture();

    return pageFuture.thenCombine(listFuture, (list, lF) ->
            ok(views.html.extractDetailsList.render(list, groupId, sortBy, order, filter))
    ).thenApplyAsync( result ->
            result, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

When the action is executed, the view will be returned as expected on occasion; even to the point of scrolling forward and backward through the records.  Most times, I receive the following error:

> Blockquote

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]]
```

I'm calling the following two methods in a database repository from the controller action:

```
public CompletionStage<PagedList<ListBillExtractDetail>> page(Long grpId, int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    return supplyAsync(() ->

            ebeanServer.find(ListBillExtractDetail.class).where()
            .eq("LBWA_ID", grpId)
            .ilike("EMP_ID", "%" + filter + "%")
            .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
            .fetch("group")
            .setFirstRow(page * pageSize)
            .setMaxRows(pageSize)
            .findPagedList(), executionContext);
}

public CompletionStage<List<BigDecimal>> totals(Long grpId){
    return supplyAsync(() -> {
        final String sql = "SELECT SUM(\"EMP_PREM\") AS totalEmployee, SUM(\"EMPLR_CONT\") AS totalEmployer," +
                " SUM(\"ACC_PREM\") AS totalPremium FROM \"lbtable\" " +
                "WHERE \"LBID\"=" + grpId;
        SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
        SqlRow row = query.findOne();
        List<BigDecimal> totals = new ArrayList<>();
        totals.add(row.getBigDecimal("totalEmployee"));
        totals.add(row.getBigDecimal("totalEmployer"));
        totals.add(row.getBigDecimal("totalPremium"));
        return totals;}, executionContext) ;
}
```

If anyone is wondering, my goal in this action is to return the paginated data to the view through one database call while returning the sum of 3 separate columns as money(bigdecimal) totals in the table footer through a second call.

Note: The view is generated without any issues when I leave off the second call to return the 3 totals columns and execute the following action instead:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> editGroup(Long groupId, int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
    return extractRepository.page(groupId, page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).thenApplyAsync(list -> {
        // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
        return ok(views.html.extractDetailsList.render(list,  groupId, sortBy, order, filter));
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

My hunch is that I'm combining the two CompletableFutures together incorrectly, although I'm not sure why it works sporadically.  Any clarification or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236209/play-framework-2-5-javaasync-throwing-completionexception help?

Comment: Thank you for the link, Nico.  It's definitely in the same ballpark, but I'm passing the current Http Execution Context. I'm guessing that I might not be placing it correctly.  The method does work randomly, which is something none of us like in our code. :)  The comments at the bottom of your link look promising.  I'll keep researching off what they've provided.